# Guardar imágenes en la base de datos vs guardar imágenes como archivos en el servidor

Tags: base-de-datos

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web que entre sus funcionalidades le permite a los usuarios registrados subir fotografías propias para que otros usuarios puedan verlas y 'votar' la calidad de las mismas. Esto implica que debo tener tanto disponibilidad de espacio para almacenar estos archivos así como asegurarme que el acceso sea rápido. Qué es preferible para implementar estos dos requisitos: ¿almaceno las fotos en formato BLOB en mi base de datos o almaceno las imágenes como archivos y guardo la ruta de cada una en la base de datos?

Como dato adicional, estoy usando Java para el desarrollo de la aplicación y mi base de datos es PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: ¿Por qué los negativos? ¿Acaso no es una pregunta adecuada para este sitio de acuerdo a lo planteado en Meta? http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/167/417

Comment: te recomiendo esta pregunta en SO en inglés http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay pero por mi experiencia personal te recomendaría guardarlos como archivos, guardando en la BD solo la ruta de las imágenes (si es ruta relativa mejor)

Answer (score 5):

Además del espacio y la rapidez de acceso, creo que deberías evaluar qué tan importante es la imagen para la entidad de negocio.

Si la imagen es crítica en cuanto a su pérdida, deberías persistirla dentro de la tabla como array de byte. Imaginemos una entidad  que representa un producto y tienes las imágenes de sus planos de construcción, en este caso si algún error hiciera que la carpeta de imágenes se perdiera sería crítico, en este caso la imagen debe formar parte de la entidad en la tabla.

Ahora si tengo una entidad persona en donde define su perfil una foto, si algo hiciera que se perdiera no sería crítico, se podría solicitar que actualice su foto en caso de hacer falta, aquí se podría ubicar la foto en una carpeta.

Quizás este razonamiento sirva para tomar la decisión de dónde ubicar la fotos.

Por otro lado también deberías analizar lo comentado aquí: [Best way to store images in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748848/best-way-to-store-images-in-postgresql). Como verás en PostgreSQL cuando un archivo excede un determinado tamaño existen otras técnicas para persistir "*Large Objects*", quizás podría ser de utilidad.
Se podría ver como algo intermedio entre grabar en una carpeta y usar un BLOB.

Comment: Hola Leandro, gracias. Sí, las imágenes tienen críticas para el modelo de negocio pero ¿no quedaría cubierto este requisito con una política de backups adecuada? ¿redundancia o copia de seguridad distribuida?

Comment: Si es verdad, si tienes una buena politica de backup reduces el problema, pero tienes que diseñar dos tecnicas de backup separadas, una para la db y otra para las carpetas, esto a veces es todo un problema, que pasa si una falla pero la otra no? empezarian las inconsistencias.
Por otro lado esta el tema de la seguridad, no es lo mismo aplicar la seguridad a la db y tener las imagenes criticas resguardadas de acceso indebidos, a tener que aplicar dos politicas diferentes, una a la db y otra sobre carpetas, esto te lo podra confirmar cualquier admin de red.