# ¿Cómo puedo gestionar un grupo de imágenes en el servidor?

Tags: nodejs, seguridad

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Node.js donde debemos mostrar la fotografía de la correspondiente persona identificada mediante huella dactilar.

Me han comentado que el manejo de la fotografía no lo debo realizar mediante una base de datos (o sea solicitarle a la respectiva tabla la imagen), sino que debo guardar esas imágenes en una carpeta del servidor y solicitarla cuando realice la identificación.

Pero de ese modo, considero que las fotografías quedan expuestas de algunas manera (por ejemplo, un usuario no identificado podría acceder a las fotografías de otro usuario si adivinase la URL de la imagen en el servidor).

¿Cómo puedo tener las fotos en una carpeta del servidor, pero prevenir su acceso no autorizado?

Comment: Hola por favor lee [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad :)

Comment: sigue basandose en opiniones, no agregas mas información; te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask la ayuda va con base en dudas especificas de código

Comment: Hola Nilson, para agregar nueva información no tienes que crear una nueva publicación y borrar la anterior, puedes pulsar en el enlace [edit] que hay en la parte inferior de la pregunta. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento.

Comment: He editado la pregunta para intentar centrarla en un problema concreto (¿cómo se prevendría el acceso a la fotografía con Node.js?) en lugar de dejarla abierta a interpretaciones. Dime si se ve bien, o si necesita cambios porque no entendí bien el problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Sobre lo de guardar la fotografía en la base de datos o en un fichero en el servidor, [aquí hay una pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2316/250) que tiene una solución que podría ayudarte con esa decisión.

Comment: simplemente usa una dirección virtual para la imagen, si no entra por ahi no se muestra. y si se entra por ahí se valida el usuario.

Comment: @aloMalbarez ¿Podrías poner una respuesta con cómo se haría eso en Node.js? En Apache sé que se podría hacer usando .htaccess, pero no cómo sería en node.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro añadido ejemplo básico usando express

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de implementar el asunto, en este caso uso `express` (con `pug` para el template html), defino un par de carpetas "públicas", el "uploads" está por fuera y cargo la imagen que corresponde al userID ( lo tengo hardcodeado para no hacerlo muy extenso).

Estructura de carpetas:

```
$ tree shadowfiles/ -L 4 -I node*

shadowfiles/
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── img
│       └── logo.jpg
├── uploads
│   ├── 00AABBCC
│   │   └── foto.png
│   └── 11CCBBAA
│       └── foto.png
└── views
    └── index.pug
```

`index.js`

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const path = require('path');
const mime = require('mime');
const fs = require('fs');

const UPLOADS_DIR = __dirname + '/uploads/';
const IMG_DIR = __dirname + '/public/img/';
const CSS_DIR = __dirname + '/public/css/';


app.set('port', 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.use('/img', express.static(IMG_DIR));
app.use('/css', express.static(CSS_DIR));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})

function getUserID(req){
  // validate session get the user ID
  var UID = '11CCBBAA';
  // return undefined;
  return UID;
}

function readImagenByID(UserID, fileName, req, res) {
  var filePath = UPLOADS_DIR + UserID +'/';
  var file = filePath + fileName;

  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
  var disposition = "inline";
  // para descarga:
  // disposition =  "attachment; filename=" + fileName;

  fs.exists(file, function(exists){
      if (exists) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          "Content-Type": mimetype,
          "Content-Disposition" : disposition
        });
        fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res);
      } else {
        // ToDo: alternativa a devolver error,
        // enviar imagen default
        res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end("ERROR File does NOT Exists");
      }
    });
}

app.get('/images/:IMG', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params);
  var UserID = getUserID(req);
  if (UserID && req.params.IMG) {
    var fileName = req.params.IMG;
    readImagenByID(UserID, fileName, req, res);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("ERROR no se quien sos o que queres");
  }
});

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () =>
  console.log('Example app listening on port '+ server.address().port)
);
```

`public/css/style.css`

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
}

img {
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

`views/index.pug`

```
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css', type='text/css' )
  body
    img(src="/img/logo.jpg")
    h1= message
    img(src="/images/foto.png")
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "shadowfiles",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "filter images by session id",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "aloMalbarez",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Fuera del ejemplo quedan el manejo de errores 404, 500 etc..., cargo el style y el logo como static para que se vea la diferencia entre publicar una carpeta/ruta con sus files y virtualizar otra carpeta/ruta.

El UserID lo tengo hardcodeado a `11CCBBAA`, si alguien supiera que la carpeta para recuperar la `foto.png` es `uploads/UserID` y quisiera hacerse el listo poniendo la "url" del usuario `00AABBCC` subiendo niveles:

```
localhost:3000/css/../../uploads/00AABBCC/foto.png
```

Recibe el error:

```
Cannot GET /uploads/00AABBCC/foto.png
```

Esto se puede enmascarar aún mas "publicando" una carpeta uploads falsa, o donde iran archivos públicos

```
const FAKE_UPLOADS_DIR = __dirname + '/public/uploads/';
app.use('/uploads', express.static(FAKE_UPLOADS_DIR));
```

Es un ejemplo básico, la clave está en validar el acceso al archivo y generar el path correcto para leerlo y enviarlo al navegador (en los headers podes enviar un expire/etag para evitar caches, etc).

El html generado por pug es bastante básico lo copio aquí para referencia:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="/img/logo.jpg"/>
  <h1>Hello there!</h1>
  <img src="/images/foto.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```