# Referenciar en el HTML/CSS una imagen que está fuera de public_html

Tags: php, html, mvc

Tengo este directorio de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente codigo le tengo en imbobiliaria/view.php y quiero hacer referencia a la carpeta uploads que está dentro de la carpeta tmp, la cual esta fuera del public_html.

```
url(../tmp/uploads/'imagen.jpg);
```

La cosa es que no me funciona y no se como escribir la ruta, lo he intentado de mil maneras...

Comment: Has probado a cerrar la comilla de la ruta?
´url(../tmp/uploads/'imagen.jpg');´

Comment: @rencinas sisis eso no tiene nada que ver, lo que pasa que no se me muestra la imagen

Comment: Intentalo así: ../../../tmp/uploads/imagen.jpg

Comment: @JulianFuentes nada, no se porque no irá

Comment: ¿Que framework utilizas?

Comment: @JulianFuentes ninguno, tengo estructura MVC

Comment: @MadCode  Obviamente, si la imagen está en un directorio que no es público, no vas a poder mostrar la imagen directamente mediante una url. Tienes varias opciones, mover la imagen a un directorio público o crear un Script php que lea la imagen y la muestre.

Comment: servidor apache, nginx, iis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas trabajando con una estructura **MVC**. En teoría deberías tener un **PHP** que llame a cada una de las vistas desde la raíz del proyecto. En tu caso no deberías tener la **URL**

> 127.0.0.1/imbobiliaria/view.php

En su lugar sería un parámetro proveniente de la URL, bien sea por **POST** o **GET**.

No necesitas colocar el "../". Ya que el archivo principal debe estar en la raíz.

```
url("tmp/uploads/imagen.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2):

Para servir archivos desde una carpeta que no está accesible desde afuera (por fuera del `public_html`) una forma de hacerlo es "virtualizar" una carpeta, los archivos que se piden dentro de esa carpeta se filtran/validan y se leen del disco enviándose al navegador como si fueras el servidor.

Para este ejemplo usamos `.htaccess` en servidor linux/apache, si necesitas para `nginx` te lo armo.

Estructura de carpetas:

```
mvc/
├── app
│   ├── cache
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── models
│   ├── uploads
│   │   ├── 404.png
│   │   ├── eye-1.png
│   │   └── eye-3.png
│   └── views
├── public
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── logo.jpg
│   ├── .htaccess
│   ├── index.php
│   └── viewimages.php
└── sys
    └── core.php
```

Aquí `public` es la carpeta `public_html` o sea el `/` desde el navegador

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# sólo servimos imágenes desde uploads
RewriteRule images/(.*).bmp$ viewimages.php [NC]
RewriteRule images/(.*).gif$ viewimages.php [NC]
RewriteRule images/(.*).jpg$ viewimages.php [NC]
RewriteRule images/(.*).jpeg$ viewimages.php [NC]
RewriteRule images/(.*).png$ viewimages.php [NC]

# descomentar para permitir todos los archivos
# RewriteRule images/(.*)$ viewimages.php [NC]
```

`index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Imágenes desde otra carpeta</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background: #FAFAFA;
  }
  h1 {
    display: block;
    width: 360px;
    height: 220px;
    background-image: url('img/logo.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    text-indent: -999px;
  }
  .ojo3 {
    background: url('images/eye-3.png') center center no-repeat #fff;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border:1px dashed red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>LOGO</h1>
  <p>una imagen de un ojo <img src="images/eye-1.png" /></p>
  <div class="ojo3">
    <p>un div con otro ojo de fondo</p>
  </div>
  <p>una imagen que no se encuentra <img src="images/cualquiera.png" /></p>
  <p>una imagen con extensión no válida <img src="images/index.php" /></p>
  <p>una imagen que trata de leer el cache subiendo una carpeta <img src="images/../cache/foto.png" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

En este `index.php` que bien podría ser un `.html` fijate cómo el logo se carga desde la carpeta `img/logo.jpg` que sí existe y de eso se encarga apache, el resto de imágenes se cargan desde la "carpeta virtual" `images/`. En un div cargo una imagen por `CSS` en otro lado cargo la imagen en un `IMG` tag.

`viewimages.php`

```
<?php
// definimos desde donde estamos hacia donde está la carpeta real
$IMAGESPATH = __DIR__.'/../app/uploads/';

// traemos el nombre de archivo pedido desde la redirección del apache
$filepath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($filepath);

// extraemos sólo nombre y extensión y le adjuntamos la carpeta real
$fileImagepath = $IMAGESPATH.$path_parts['basename'];

// estaslíneas las descomentas para ver cómo es la magia
/*
var_dump($filepath, $fileImagepath, pathinfo($filepath));
die();
//*/

// si el archivo en la carpeta real existe
if (file_exists($fileImagepath))
{
  // modificamos la fecha de acceso (unix)
  touch($fileImagepath,filemtime($fileImagepath),time()); 

  // vemos que cabecera enviar según la extensión
  switch(strtolower($path_parts['extension']))
  {
    case "gif":
      header("Content-type: image/gif");
      break;
      case "jpg":
      case "jpeg":
      header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
      break;
      case "png":
      header("Content-type: image/png");
      break;
      case "bmp":
      header("Content-type: image/bmp");
      break;
    }

    // enviamos las cabeceras con cuanto pesa y cuando fue modificado
    // para manejar cabeceras de "última vez modificado" que
    // puede haber pedido el navegador ver las referencias
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileImagepath));
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime($fileImagepath)));
    readfile($fileImagepath);

  }
  else
  {
    // si el archivo no existe o no reconocemos la extensión
    // enviamos una imagen default 404 con su cabecera de error
    header( "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($IMAGESPATH."404.png"));
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'));
    readfile($IMAGESPATH."404.png");
  }
  /*
  Based on Script
  By Samer Mhana
  www.dorar-aliraq.net
  */
?>
```

Referencias:

*script en el cual se basa el ejemplo*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453207/1423096

*apache modrewrite*
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

*fechas en headers*
https://stackoverflow.com/q/21120882/1423096

*304 Not Modified*
https://stackoverflow.com/q/10847157/1423096

de yapa la misma técnica para NodeJS : [¿Cómo puedo gestionar un grupo de imágenes en el servidor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176879/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-gestionar-un-grupo-de-im%C3%A1genes-en-el-servidor/177031#177031)

Answer (score 0):

Sin mover la carpeta de imágenes te podría funcionar:

```
../../tmp/uploads/imagen.jpg
```

Tu subes un nivel y hay un comentario que te dice 3 niveles, pero por lo que veo en la imagen tendrías que subir dos niveles para acceder a tmp, inmobiliaria está dentro de componentes que está dentro de public_html y esta carpeta esta en el mismo nivel que tmp, por lo que tendrías que subir dos niveles para poder acceder a tmp.