# Cómo configurar htaccess para mostrar imágenes de un directorio que no este en el directorio raíz

Tags: php, php7, .htaccess, apache2

Estoy trabajando con PHP y apache, y tengo configurado un router que me muestra las imágenes que están en el sitio público y root sin problema, pero al intentar mostrar las imágenes del sitio privado no las carga.

Necesito guardar imágenes en el sitio privado y mostrárselas sólo a los propietarios. No creo que guardar las imágenes en el sitio público sea lo ideal.

El enrutador está configurado para que todas las rutas comiencen públicamente con "/" y no con "../".

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto localmente y que funcione correctamente en un servidor real?

//estructura del proyecto:

```
app/
-------/public     <======Root
---------------/css
---------------/img
---------------/js
---------------/index.php
---------------/.htaccess
-------/private
---------------/imgs    
---------------/pages
---------------/dashboard.php
-------/lib
-----------/route.php
```

// .htaccess configuración

```
AddType Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? [QSA,L]
```

//html

```
 <span> <img src="img/test2.jpg" width="30px"> public</span>
   <span> <img src="../private/imgs/test1.jpg" width="30px"> private</span>
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178524/81450